# Whats the best method to measure timespans between two timestamps

Tags: awk, timestamp, gawk

What is the most effective method to count, **measure** (calculate) **timespans between two timestamps** from a logfile?
I know the stupid solution in Excel/Numbers/Refine, but I am looking for a smart awk-oneliner.

Example:
An elevator with an automatic door system operates on n floors.

The elevator opens the door:

`Start Move to Work_position`

The elevator door is open:

`End Move to Work_position`

The elevator closes the door

`Start Move to Home_Position
End Move to Home_Position`

The (prepared) logfile:

```
Elevator_021 logger:  2017-02-13 13:11:33.735 [MONITORING] CYL_A1; Floor_12 Door ;Start Move to Work_position  
Elevator_021 logger:  2017-02-13 13:11:34.800 [MONITORING] CYL_A1; Floor_12 Door ;End Move to Work_position  

Elevator_021 logger:  2017-02-13 13:26:12.893 [MONITORING] CYL_A1; Floor_12 Door ;Start Move to Home_Position  
Elevator_021 logger:  2017-02-13 13:26:13.898 [MONITORING] CYL_A1; Floor_12 Door ;End Move to Home_Position  

Elevator_021 logger:  2017-02-13 14:51:03.211 [MONITORING] CYL_A1; Floor_12 Door ;Start Move to Work_position  
Elevator_021 logger:  2017-02-13 14:51:04.276 [MONITORING] CYL_A1; Floor_12 Door ;End Move to Work_position
```

> **I'm heading for an output like this:**

```
Elevator_021 logger:  2017-02-13 13:11:33.735 [MONITORING] CYL_A1; Floor_12 Door ;Start Move to Work_position  
Elevator_021 logger:  2017-02-13 13:11:34.800 [MONITORING] CYL_A1; Floor_12 Door ;End Move to Work_position  
to Work 1065 ms  

Elevator_021 logger:  2017-02-13 13:26:12.893 [MONITORING] CYL_A1; Floor_12 Door ;Start Move to Home_Position  
Elevator_021 logger:  2017-02-13 13:26:13.898 [MONITORING] CYL_A1; Floor_12 Door ;End Move to Home_Position  
to Home 1005 ms  

Elevator_021 logger:  2017-02-13 14:51:03.211 [MONITORING] CYL_A1; Floor_12 Door ;Start Move to Work_position  
Elevator_021 logger:  2017-02-13 14:51:04.276 [MONITORING] CYL_A1; Floor_12 Door ;End Move to Work_position  
to Work 3976 ms
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `gawk` to do something like:

```
awk 'function dtime(s) {
         x=match($0, /([0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}\s[0-9:]+)(\.[0-9]+).*([0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}\s[0-9:]+)(\.[0-9]+).*(to \w+)_/, arr)
         if (x) {
              s1=arr[1]
              s2=arr[3]
              gsub(/[-:]/, " ", s1)
              gsub(/[-:]/, " ", s2)
              t1=mktime(s1)+arr[2]
              t2=mktime(s2)+arr[4]
              return arr[5] " " (t2-t1)*1000 " ms"
         }
         else
              return ""
         }
BEGIN   {RS=ORS="\n\n"} 
        {print $0 " -> " dtime($0) }' file
```

Prints:

Elevator_021 logger: 2017-02-13 13:11:33.735 [MONITORING] CYL_A1; Floor_12 Door ;Start Move to Work_position Elevator_021 logger: 2017-02-13 13:11:34.800 [MONITORING] CYL_A1; Floor_12 Door ;End Move to Work_position -> to Work 1065 ms

Elevator_021 logger: 2017-02-13 13:26:12.893 [MONITORING] CYL_A1; Floor_12 Door ;Start Move to Home_Position Elevator_021 logger: 2017-02-13 13:26:13.898 [MONITORING] CYL_A1; Floor_12 Door ;End Move to Home_Position -> to Home 1005 ms

Elevator_021 logger: 2017-02-13 14:51:03.211 [MONITORING] CYL_A1; Floor_12 Door ;Start Move to Work_position Elevator_021 logger: 2017-02-13 14:51:04.276 [MONITORING] CYL_A1; Floor_12 Door ;End Move to Work_position -> to Work 1065 ms

Comment: thx!   
But, no! 

 awk: syntax error at source line 2 in function dtime context is x=match($0, /([0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}\s[0-9:]+)(\. [0-9]+).*([0-9]{4}-‌​[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}\s[‌​0-9:]+)(\.[0-9]+).*(‌​to >>> \w+)_/, <<< awk: illegal statement at source line 2  in function dtime awk: illegal statement at source line 2 in Funktion stimme

Comment: It will be far from a 1 liner in POSIX awk since it has no time functions. You could investigate using `date` for the time stamp conversion or use Perl or install gawk.

Comment: It works - switched to another OS-X machine.
But only with "pre-grouping" of the related lines - needs one empty line between the related pairs.

Comment: That is from `RS=ORS="\n\n"` which is how your example was presented. If the actual data is just free form text, that would require additional steps.